# reflection matrix does not work properly

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I tried [this tutorial](http://khayyam.kaplinski.com/2011/09/reflective-water-with-glsl-part-i.html) and this is how i create and use the reflection matrix (my water plane is z = 0):

```
glm::mat4 mReflection = glm::mat4
    (
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    );

camera.setViewMatrix(mReflection * camera.View());
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
```

shader:

```
vec4 mvpvertex = MVP_reflection * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
vec2 projCoord = mvpvertex.xy / mvpvertex.w;
projCoord = vec2(0.5, 0.5) + 0.5 * projCoord;
projCoord = clamp(projCoord, 0.0, 1.0);
```

But the whole scene seems to be flipped arround. The things i should see the reflection of in front of me are behind me and vice versa. I tried some more matrix transformations but none if my tries worked.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're multiplying the reflection matrix from the left, this means that it is applied after the view matrix. So a reflection in the z-direction, which is what your matrix defines, will flip front and back.

I think you have two options to fix this:

1. Apply the reflection before the view transformation. Sine the water plane is at z = 0 in your world space, reflecting in z-direction would then be correct. To do this, you could either make the reflection part of your model transformation (if you have one in code not shown), or swap the order of the multiplication:

   ```
   camera.setViewMatrix(camera.View(), mReflection);
   ```
2. Since you're talking about a water reflection, I figure that the reflection swaps up-down, which (unless you are using a very unusual projection matrix) is the y-direction after the model and view transformations have been applied. So if you want to apply the reflection after the view transformation, you need a y-reflection:

   ```
   1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
   0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
   0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
   0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0
   ```

I haven't studied the tutorial you're following in detail, so I'm not sure which of the two options will work better in the context. From a superficial look, it seems like they actually end up flipping twice, both before and after the view transformation. You will have to figure out the details, but I hope this will resolve your main obstacle.

The above assumes that you're using a matrix library that operates in the most standard way, where matrices are constructed for vectors being multiplied from the right. The order of multiplication would revert if you operate with row major matrices, and then transpose the matrices when feeding them into the shader.